# Can't get basic AJAX script to work, new to jQuery and Javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to get this AJAX request to work. Any body sections hide, like what my first line after the event handler says to do. However, the content from about.html doesn't load and I get no error message. Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


      //AJAX About.html
      $('#about-button').on('click', function() {
        $('body section').hide(),

        $.ajax('about.html'), {
          success: function(response) {
            $('.about-page').html(response).slideDown()
          },
          error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
            $('body').html("<p> 'Error: ' + errorType + ' with message ' + errorMessage </p>")
          },
          timeout: 3000
        };
      });



    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct.  You are closing the arguments to `$.ajax()` prematurely and thus not passing the object to it.

Instead of this:

```
   $.ajax('about.html'), {
      success: function(response) {
        $('.about-page').html(response).slideDown()
      },
      error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
        $('body').html("<p> 'Error: ' + errorType + ' with message ' + errorMessage </p>")
      },
      timeout: 3000
    };
```

You need this so the options object is actually passed to `$.ajax()` as the second argument:

```
   $.ajax('about.html', {
      success: function(response) {
        $('.about-page').html(response).slideDown();
      },
      error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
        $('body').html("<p> 'Error: ' + errorType + ' with message ' + errorMessage </p>");
      },
      timeout: 3000
   });
```